# Migrating an ISAPI classic application to IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022 Standard - path info calls failing

Tags: web-server, iis-10, isapi

Now migrating an ISAPI classic application to IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022 Standard.

The application uses path info to call many different functions in the ISAPI app. Calls are now failing with ***HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found -  http//webserver/appfunction*** .

In IIS 7 there was web configuration file: ***system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config***
(see [***Getting Started with Configuration in IIS 7 and Above...Configuration File Hierarchy***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/getting-started-with-configuration-in-iis-7-and-above)  )

Cannot find this file. Has it been deprecated? Are the settings in that file - specifically `allowpathinfo` for a particular website - controlled somewhere else?

I have tried adding `allowpathinfo="true"` to web.config in the local website directory, but this did not help.

Where are path info settings now controlled in IIS.10? How might I fix this problem?

*(I am not a new user - old profile was lost)*

Comment: If you cannot find `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`, I am afraid you are probably not using a normal Windows/IIS machine. IIS 10 still uses exactly the same file.

Comment: @LexLi - I did search on C:\ and subdirectories with File Locator Pro - maybe I messed something up - will try again.

Comment: @LexLi - found the file, in the old place. Adding  `allowpathinfo="true" ` didn't help, so I have some serious analysis to do...